# Exposing pandas DataFrame to TraitsGUI Editable Table

Tags: python, pandas, enthought, traitsui

I have noticed in the Enthought Canopy demos, there are several bits of code that expose lists and numpy arrays as a TraitsUI Editable Table.  I am looking to do the same for a Pandas DataFrame.  Essentially, I'd like to be able to edit a couple of columns in my DataFrame and have a callback that re-calculates other columns (that are dependent on the edited columns).

Does anyone know of any sample code that might get me started with exposing a DF object via a TraitsUI table?